# python: file to file transcription

Tags: python

I have a .txt which contains a list of codes:

```
1001
1002
1003
1004
1005
1006
1007
1008
0101
0102
0103
0104
0105
0106
```

and another file which contains the meaning of each code and has the following structure:

```
{
    "more": false,
    "classCode": "H0",
    "className": "HS1992",
    "minimumInputLength": 2,
    "results": [{
        "id": "ALL",
        "text": "All HS1992 commodities",
        "parent": "#"
    },
    {
        "id": "TOTAL",
        "text": "Total of all HS1992 commodities",
        "parent": "#"
    },
    {
        "id": "AG2",
        "text": "AG2 - All 2-digit HS1992 commodities",
        "parent": "#"
    },
    {
        "id": "AG4",
        "text": "AG4 - All 4-digit HS1992 commodities",
        "parent": "#"
    },
    {
        "id": "AG6",
        "text": "AG6 - All 6-digit HS1992 commodities",
        "parent": "#"
    },
    {
        "id": "01",
        "text": "01 - Animals; live",
        "parent": "TOTAL"
    },
    {
        "id": "0101",
        "text": "0101 - Horses, asses, mules and hinnies; live",
        "parent": "01"
    },
    {
        "id": "010111",
        "text": "010111 - Horses; live, pure-bred breeding animals",
        "parent": "0101"
    },
    {
        "id": "010119",
        "text": "010119 - Horses; live, other than pure-bred breeding animals",
        "parent": "0101"
    },
    {
        "id": "010120",
        "text": "010120 - Asses, mules and hinnies; live",
        "parent": "0101"
    },
    {
        "id": "0102",
        "text": "0102 - Bovine animals; live",
        "parent": "01"
    },
    {
        "id": "010210",
        "text": "010210 - Bovine animals; live, pure-bred breeding animals",
        "parent": "0102"
    },
    {
        "id": "010290",
        "text": "010290 - Bovine animals; live, other than pure-bred breeding animals",
        "parent": "0102"
    },
    {
        "id": "0103",
        "text": "0103 - Swine; live",
        "parent": "01"
    },
```

and so on.

What I would like to do is write a third file in which each row contains the explanation of the code (i.e. the expression that follows the word "text") in the corresponding line in the first file.

For example, the first three lines should be:

```
0101 - Horses, asses, mules and hinnies; live
0102 - Bovine animals; live
0103 - Swine; live
```

The only think I could come up with is an if cycle, but the code are 1233, so I'd have to write 1233 conditions.

Is there a shorter way? Maybe based on the fact that the codes are unique and the description is just after the code in the second file

Comment: Hint: You do not need to write 1233 conditions. Use a `dict` instead

Comment: May I ask you to be a little bit more specific?

Comment: Convert the second file to a dict, then you can use it as a lookup table

Comment: But I don't need all the file to be converted, I just need the expression after "text" and only the for the codes whose id is composed by four digits. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @mousetail the best way would be to import the second file as a dictionary with key being the code and text being the value.

```py
import json

with open("path_to_file", "r") as json_file:
    file_contents = json.load(json_file)
codes_to_text_dict = {result["id"]: result["text"] for result in file_contents["results"]}
```

Then just read the input file, find the text for each line and write it to the output file:

```py
with open("input.txt") as input_file, open("output.txt", "w+") as output_file:
    for line in input_file.readlines():
        output_file.write(codes_to_text_dict[line.strip()] + "\n")
```

Comment: Do I need to change the structure of the file? I get the following error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prova.py", line 3, in <module>
    file_contents = json.load("HS.txt")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/_init_.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: Sorry I wrote the code incorrectly. I will update my answer

Comment: Sorry to bother you again but I still get an error I can't understand: Traceback (most recent call last): File "prova.py", line 5, in <module>
    file_contents = json.load(json_file)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/_init_.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xca in position 12: invalid continuation byte

Comment: I tried it with the file snippet you shared and it does not give any errors... Anyhow it looks like an encoding error. Can you make sure that the json file is encoded in UTF8?

Comment: Actually the file is a .txt, not a .json. Do I need to convert it into a .json?

Comment: File extension does not matter, what matters is that the content is valid json. If you need to check https://jsoneditoronline.org is a nice online json formatter and editor

Comment: Grea, solved it. The very last thing about the code. What is lines? Is it referred to the first file?

Comment: It was assuming you red lined from the first file. Something like `lines = first_file.readlines()`. If you can be more specific on what you need to do with the output (like printing it to screen or saving it to a new file or overwriting the first file) I can update my answer to be more specific (and complete)

Comment: I'd like to write the output to a new file. Grazie mille

Comment: This should do what you need. Prego